# Integrating $\int_{\ln2}^{\ln3}$ $\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2x}}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I integrate the following.

$$
\int_{\ln2}^{\ln3}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2x}}}\,dx
$$

I think I have to use the $\arcsin(x)$ formula.

Which means would I use $y=u^2$ with $u=e^{-x}$ but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Substituting $t=e^{-x}$ should make it look sufficiently like the derivative of $\arcsin t$

Comment: The Maple code $$with(Student[Calculus1]);
IntTutor(exp(-x)/sqrt(1-exp(-2*x)), x = ln(2) .. ln(3));
 $$ calculates it step by step with explanations and hints. See [the output](http://rapidshare.com/share/352007E0AACC50AA2B6AC9F24AFD0BDE) and [this link](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work
$$
\int_{\ln 2}^{\ln 3}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2x}}}dx
\overset{\quad u=e^{-x}}{=}
-\int_{1/2}^{1/3}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}dx
$$
$$
=-\arcsin u\Biggl|_{1/2}^{1/3}
=-\arcsin(1/3)+\frac{\pi}{6}
$$

Comment: One thing I thought is that the du of e^-x would be -1e^-x But I see you use the u substituion and put -1du I think...

Comment: Norbert, trying using $ \overset{u = e^{-x}}{=} $ to display substitutions. The code is \overset{u = e^{-x}}{=}. I think it makes the notation a lot clearer (and more technically correct).

Answer (score 1):

Setting
$$
t=e^{-x},\ t=\sin\theta
$$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{\ln2}^{\ln3}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2x}}}\,dx
&=&\int_{\frac13}^{\frac12}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt=\int_{\arcsin\frac13}^{\arcsin\frac12}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta\\
&=&\int_{\arcsin\frac13}^{\frac\pi6}\,d\theta=\frac\pi6-\arcsin\frac13.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sin t = e^{-x}$. Then $\cos t \cdot dt = -e^{-x}dx$.
$$\begin{align}
\int^{\ln3}_{\ln2}\frac{e^{-x}dx}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2x}}}
=& \int^{\arcsin\frac{1}{3}}_{\arcsin\frac{1}{2}}\frac{-\cos t \cdot dt}{\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}t}}\\
=& \int^{\arcsin\frac{1}{3}}_{\arcsin\frac{1}{2}}\frac{-\cos t \cdot dt}{\cos t}\\
=& \int^{\arcsin\frac{1}{2}}_{\arcsin\frac{1}{3}}dt\\
=& \arcsin \frac{1}{2} - \arcsin\frac{1}{3}
\end{align}$$